# 'boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types

Tags: boost, visual-studio-2015, boost-variant, boost-signals2, cpp-netlib

I'm not able to build two of my projects with Boost libraries 1.61.0 and Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.

These projects used to build fine for years with various combinations of Visual Studio and Boost versions, and I didn't change anything in my code except from updating Visual Studio and Boost libraries.

The error I get with both of these projects is:

```
'boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
```

In both of these projects I don't use boost::variant directly from my code. In one case it looks like boost::variant is being used from boost::signals2 (which I also don't use directly from my code) and in the other case it looks like boost::variant is being used from Cpp-Netlib 0.11.2.

Here are the relevant parts of the output logs of these two projects:

---

```
1>d:\libraries\boost_1_61_0\boost\variant\detail\visitation_impl.hpp(267): error C2665: 'boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
1>  d:\libraries\boost_1_61_0\boost\variant\detail\visitation_impl.hpp(201): note: could be 'void boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl<next_which,next_step,Visitor,VoidPtrCV,NoBackupFlag>(const int,const int,Visitor &,VoidPtrCV,boost::mpl::false_,NoBackupFlag,Which *,step0 *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Visitor=boost::detail::variant::destroyer,
1>              VoidPtrCV=void *,
1>              NoBackupFlag=boost::variant<boost::shared_ptr<void>,boost::signals2::detail::foreign_void_shared_ptr,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_>::has_fallback_type_,
1>              Which=next_which,
1>              step0=next_step
1>          ]
1>  d:\libraries\boost_1_61_0\boost\variant\detail\visitation_impl.hpp(183): note: or       'void boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl<next_which,next_step,Visitor,VoidPtrCV,NoBackupFlag>(int,int,Visitor &,VPCV,boost::mpl::true_,NBF,W *,S *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Visitor=boost::detail::variant::destroyer,
1>              VoidPtrCV=void *,
1>              NoBackupFlag=boost::variant<boost::shared_ptr<void>,boost::signals2::detail::foreign_void_shared_ptr,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_>::has_fallback_type_,
1>              VPCV=void *,
1>              NBF=boost::variant<boost::shared_ptr<void>,boost::signals2::detail::foreign_void_shared_ptr,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_>::has_fallback_type_,
1>              W=next_which,
1>              S=next_step
1>          ]
1>  d:\libraries\boost_1_61_0\boost\variant\detail\visitation_impl.hpp(267): note: while trying to match the argument list '(const int, const int, boost::detail::variant::destroyer, void *, is_apply_visitor_unrolled, boost::variant<boost::shared_ptr<void>,boost::signals2::detail::foreign_void_shared_ptr,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_>::has_fallback_type_, next_which *, next_step *)'
1>  d:\libraries\boost_1_61_0\boost\variant\variant.hpp(2326): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl<first_which,first_step,Visitor,VoidPtrCV,boost::variant<boost::shared_ptr<void>,boost::signals2::detail::foreign_void_shared_ptr,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_>::has_fallback_type_>(const int,const int,Visitor &,VoidPtrCV,boost::mpl::false_,NoBackupFlag,Which *,step0 *)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Visitor=boost::detail::variant::destroyer,
1>              VoidPtrCV=void *,
1>              NoBackupFlag=boost::variant<boost::shared_ptr<void>,boost::signals2::detail::foreign_void_shared_ptr,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_>::has_fallback_type_,
1>              Which=first_which,
1>              step0=first_step
1>          ]
1>  d:\libraries\boost_1_61_0\boost\variant\variant.hpp(2337): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::variant<boost::shared_ptr<void>,boost::signals2::detail::foreign_void_shared_ptr,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_>::internal_apply_visitor_impl<Visitor,void*>(int,int,Visitor &,VoidPtrCV)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Visitor=boost::detail::variant::destroyer,
1>              VoidPtrCV=void *
1>          ]
1>  d:\libraries\boost_1_61_0\boost\variant\variant.hpp(2335): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::variant<boost::shared_ptr<void>,boost::signals2::detail::foreign_void_shared_ptr,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_>::internal_apply_visitor_impl<Visitor,void*>(int,int,Visitor &,VoidPtrCV)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Visitor=boost::detail::variant::destroyer,
1>              VoidPtrCV=void *
1>          ]
1>  d:\libraries\boost_1_61_0\boost\variant\variant.hpp(1345): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::variant<boost::shared_ptr<void>,boost::signals2::detail::foreign_void_shared_ptr,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_>::internal_apply_visitor<boost::detail::variant::destroyer>(Visitor &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Visitor=boost::detail::variant::destroyer
1>          ]
1>  d:\libraries\boost_1_61_0\boost\variant\variant.hpp(1345): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::variant<boost::shared_ptr<void>,boost::signals2::detail::foreign_void_shared_ptr,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_>::internal_apply_visitor<boost::detail::variant::destroyer>(Visitor &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Visitor=boost::detail::variant::destroyer
1>          ]
1>  d:\libraries\boost_1_61_0\boost\variant\variant.hpp(1343): note: while compiling class template member function 'void boost::variant<boost::shared_ptr<void>,boost::signals2::detail::foreign_void_shared_ptr,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_>::destroy_content(void) noexcept'
1>  d:\libraries\boost_1_61_0\boost\variant\variant.hpp(1352): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::variant<boost::shared_ptr<void>,boost::signals2::detail::foreign_void_shared_ptr,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_>::destroy_content(void) noexcept' being compiled
1>  d:\libraries\boost_1_61_0\boost\signals2\slot_base.hpp(47): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::variant<boost::shared_ptr<void>,boost::signals2::detail::foreign_void_shared_ptr,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_>' being compiled
```

---

```
1>d:\libraries\boost_1_61_0\boost\variant\detail\visitation_impl.hpp(267): error C2665: 'boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
1>  d:\libraries\boost_1_61_0\boost\variant\detail\visitation_impl.hpp(201): note: could be 'void boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl<next_which,next_step,Visitor,VoidPtrCV,NoBackupFlag>(const int,const int,Visitor &,VoidPtrCV,boost::mpl::false_,NoBackupFlag,Which *,step0 *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Visitor=boost::detail::variant::copy_into,
1>              VoidPtrCV=const void *,
1>              NoBackupFlag=boost::variant<uint16_t,boost::shared_future<uint16_t>,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_>::has_fallback_type_,
1>              Which=next_which,
1>              step0=next_step
1>          ]
1>  d:\libraries\boost_1_61_0\boost\variant\detail\visitation_impl.hpp(183): note: or       'void boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl<next_which,next_step,Visitor,VoidPtrCV,NoBackupFlag>(int,int,Visitor &,VPCV,boost::mpl::true_,NBF,W *,S *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Visitor=boost::detail::variant::copy_into,
1>              VoidPtrCV=const void *,
1>              NoBackupFlag=boost::variant<uint16_t,boost::shared_future<uint16_t>,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_>::has_fallback_type_,
1>              VPCV=const void *,
1>              NBF=boost::variant<uint16_t,boost::shared_future<uint16_t>,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_>::has_fallback_type_,
1>              W=next_which,
1>              S=next_step
1>          ]
1>  d:\libraries\boost_1_61_0\boost\variant\detail\visitation_impl.hpp(267): note: while trying to match the argument list '(const int, const int, boost::detail::variant::copy_into, const void *, is_apply_visitor_unrolled, boost::variant<uint16_t,boost::shared_future<uint16_t>,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_>::has_fallback_type_, next_which *, next_step *)'
1>  d:\libraries\boost_1_61_0\boost\variant\variant.hpp(2326): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl<first_which,first_step,Visitor,VoidPtrCV,boost::variant<uint16_t,boost::shared_future<uint16_t>,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_>::has_fallback_type_>(const int,const int,Visitor &,VoidPtrCV,boost::mpl::false_,NoBackupFlag,Which *,step0 *)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Visitor=boost::detail::variant::copy_into,
1>              VoidPtrCV=const void *,
1>              NoBackupFlag=boost::variant<uint16_t,boost::shared_future<uint16_t>,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_>::has_fallback_type_,
1>              Which=first_which,
1>              step0=first_step
1>          ]
1>  d:\libraries\boost_1_61_0\boost\variant\variant.hpp(2348): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::variant<uint16_t,boost::shared_future<uint16_t>,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_>::internal_apply_visitor_impl<Visitor,const void*>(int,int,Visitor &,VoidPtrCV)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Visitor=boost::detail::variant::copy_into,
1>              VoidPtrCV=const void *
1>          ]
1>  d:\libraries\boost_1_61_0\boost\variant\variant.hpp(2346): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::variant<uint16_t,boost::shared_future<uint16_t>,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_>::internal_apply_visitor_impl<Visitor,const void*>(int,int,Visitor &,VoidPtrCV)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Visitor=boost::detail::variant::copy_into,
1>              VoidPtrCV=const void *
1>          ]
1>  d:\libraries\boost_1_61_0\boost\variant\variant.hpp(1746): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::variant<uint16_t,boost::shared_future<uint16_t>,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_>::internal_apply_visitor<boost::detail::variant::copy_into>(Visitor &) const' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Visitor=boost::detail::variant::copy_into
1>          ]
1>  d:\libraries\boost_1_61_0\boost\variant\variant.hpp(1746): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::variant<uint16_t,boost::shared_future<uint16_t>,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_>::internal_apply_visitor<boost::detail::variant::copy_into>(Visitor &) const' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Visitor=boost::detail::variant::copy_into
1>          ]
1>  d:\libraries\boost_1_61_0\boost\variant\variant.hpp(1742): note: while compiling class template member function 'boost::variant<uint16_t,boost::shared_future<uint16_t>,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_>::variant(const boost::variant<uint16_t,boost::shared_future<uint16_t>,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_> &)'
1>  d:\libraries\cpp-netlib-0.11.2-final\build\install\include\boost\network\protocol\http\message\directives\status.hpp(36): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::variant<uint16_t,boost::shared_future<uint16_t>,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_>::variant(const boost::variant<uint16_t,boost::shared_future<uint16_t>,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_> &)' being compiled
1>  d:\libraries\cpp-netlib-0.11.2-final\build\install\include\boost\network\protocol\http\message\directives\status.hpp(29): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::variant<uint16_t,boost::shared_future<uint16_t>,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_>' being compiled
```

---

Is this a bug in the boost libraries?

Comment: Where's the code? It should be possible to reproduce with at most two stubbed out classes, IYAM. Perhaps you mean it's in just the headers, in that case, where's the MVCE/SSCCE that includes those headers?

Comment: For the second instance of this error (the one related to cpp-netlib), it is very easy to reproduce: 
1) Create a new C++ console project with Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 
2) Add include directories for cpp-netlib 0.11.2 and boost 1.61.0
3) In the main source file add #include <boost/network.hpp>

Comment: And the first instance of the error is even easier to reproduce: 1) Create a new C++ console project with Visual Studio 2015 Update 3  2) Add include directory for boost 1.61.0 3) In the main source file add #include <boost/signals2/slot_base.hpp>

Comment: Both should likely be filled as issues with the respective library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have a broken Boost installation.  Are you keeping multiple versions of Boost laying around?  There are multiple examples of Boost 1.61.0 and Visual Studio 2015 update 3 working together successfully on the web, [though this one does say there are some issues with the new SFINAE feature](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/06/07/expression-sfinae-improvements-in-vs-2015-update-3/).

Try removing old Boost installations and make a clean install of [Boost 1.61.0 from the Boost distribution](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/more/getting_started/windows.html).

It is also possible that Visual Studio was corrupted during the install or update, but I have seen fewer of those types of problems.

Comment: You're right! Looks like my boost installation got corrupted! I downloaded and built it again with the same settings, and now the errors are gone. Strange.... Thanks for your help!